# Numpy savetxt with mixed data

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, typeerror

I have to save an array containing strings as the first columns and some integers/floating point numbers as the remaining columns. I have tried

```
rows = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value = np.random.rand(3,3)
np.savetxt('out.csv', np.c_[rows, value], fmt='%s %.2f %.2f %.2f')
```

but results in the error

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%s %.2f %.2f %.2f')
```

Can I do this with `numpy.savetxt` ?

PS: The following code works, but I cannot restrict the number of digits.

```
np.savetxt('out.csv', np.c_[rows, value], fmt='%s')
```

The output of above command is

```
a 0.20196028482097483 0.5926321104002011 0.3249535106614311
b 0.061901131792619135 0.2124539226474711 0.7246679538084769
c 0.8459228604109359 0.1808180141813832 0.6723417117192844
```

The output I need is

```
a 0.20 0.59 0.32
b 0.06 0.21 0.72
c 0.85 0.18 0.67
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy arrays can only have 1 dtype. Because your first column is a string, your whole array is converted to a string. Therefore you can not use `%.2f`, instead you can use `%.4s` like this:

```
np.savetxt('out.csv', np.c_[rows, value], fmt='%s %.4s %.4s %.4s')
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at what you are trying to save:

```
In [457]: arr = np.c_[rows, value]
In [458]: arr
Out[458]: 
array([['a', '0.5798052037530684', '0.340056048668929',
        '0.9826015148933265'],
       ['b', '0.686642341561269', '0.22840250256173122',
        '0.874930037338561'],
       ['c', '0.38991473280876576', '0.1744123512308029',
        '0.7399608481535285']], dtype='<U32')
```

By this simple column stacking you've created an array of strings.  The only way that can be formatted is with the `%s`.

You need instead to create a structured array:

For that I can create a list of tuples, and the appropriate dtype.

My first try is clean, but savetxt can't handle the nested list any better:

```
In [460]: arr = np.array(list(zip(rows, value)), 'U3,3f')
In [461]: arr
Out[461]: 
array([('a', [0.5798052 , 0.34005606, 0.9826015 ]),
       ('b', [0.68664235, 0.2284025 , 0.87493   ]),
       ('c', [0.38991472, 0.17441235, 0.73996085])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<f4', (3,))])
```

Instead we need separate fields for each float value:

```
In [462]: arr = np.array(list(zip(rows, *value)), 'U3,f,f,f')
In [463]: arr
Out[463]: 
array([('a', 0.5798052 , 0.68664235, 0.38991472),
       ('b', 0.34005606, 0.2284025 , 0.17441235),
       ('c', 0.9826015 , 0.87493   , 0.73996085)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

Now we can use your `fmt`:

```
In [464]: np.savetxt('test.txt', arr, fmt='%s %.2f %.2f %.2f')
In [465]: cat test.txt
a 0.58 0.69 0.39
b 0.34 0.23 0.17
c 0.98 0.87 0.74
```

Ooops - this has transposed the `value` array - I should have used:

```
arr = np.array(list(zip(rows, *value.T)), 'U3,f,f,f')
```

Another option is to create an object dtype array:

```
In [466]: M = np.zeros((3,4),object)
In [467]: M[:,0] = rows
In [468]: M[:,1:] = value
In [469]: M
Out[469]: 
array([['a', 0.5798052037530684, 0.340056048668929, 0.9826015148933265],
       ['b', 0.686642341561269, 0.22840250256173122, 0.874930037338561],
       ['c', 0.38991473280876576, 0.1744123512308029, 0.7399608481535285]],
      dtype=object)
In [470]: np.savetxt('test.txt', M, fmt='%s %.2f %.2f %.2f')
In [471]: cat test.txt
a 0.58 0.34 0.98
b 0.69 0.23 0.87
c 0.39 0.17 0.74
```